# How to separate the kernel file CUDA with the main .cpp file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

When I build the code with kernelAdd() function and main() function in the same file mainFunc.cu, it's ok.

But when I separate the kernelAdd() function in the kernelAdd.cu file and the main file in main.cpp file, it's built with the 2 errors:

"error C2065: 'add' : undeclared identifier"

and "error C2059: syntax error : '<'"

I built them in Visual Studio 2008 and Cuda v5.0.

And how do I correct its errors?

Thanks!

kernelAdd.cu

```
__global__ void add(int a, int b, int *c) {
*c = a + b;
}
```

mainFunc.cpp

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {

int c;
int *devC;

cudaMalloc((void**) &devC, sizeof(int));
add<<<1,1>>>(2,7,devC);
cudaMemcpy(&c, devC, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

printf("2+7=%d\n", c);

cudaFree(devC);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only addition to C to make CUDA C is the triple angle-bracket syntax to launch a kernel (`<<<>>>`). Everything else uses existing C features. Specifying a function as `__global__` will cause nvcc to compile it for the device and create the symbols etc. so that it can be called from the host.

This means that:

1. The device code (`__global__` function etc.) must be in a .cu file.
2. The host code that uses the `<<<>>>` syntax to launch a kernel must be in a .cu file.

You can still have all your other host code in .cpp files, you just need to put a stub in the .cu file to call the kernel, e.g. `void launch_add(...) { add<<<...>>>(...); }`.

Answer (score 6):

> error C2065: 'add' : undeclared identifier

This error has nothing to do with CUDA. The `add` function belongs to one compilation unit (`kernelAdd.cu`), while the other compilation unit (`mainFunc.cpp`) does not know anything about it. In order to give it this information you have to create an additional header file `kernelAdd.h` with the function declaration:

```
__global__ void add(int a, int b, int *c);
```

And include it in the `mainFunc.cpp`:

```
#include "kernelAdd.h"
```

Every `cu` or `cpp` file is compiled separately and only knows about the functions it sees in the header files it includes.

> error C2059: syntax error : '<'

Now I'm guessing here (don't have VS, or even Windows to check), but it seems that VS chooses the compiler for each of the files in the project based on its extension. Thus `mainFunc.cpp` gets compiled with a common C++ compiler, but the `<<<>>>` syntax for kernel calls does not belong to the standard C++ — it is from CUDA. All the CUDA-specific syntax must be used only in those files that are going to be compiled with `nvcc`.

So one way to solve your problem is to rename `mainFunc.cpp` to `mainFunc.cu`. You can still keep your main file `.cpp`, of course, but then you will have to move the kernel call to some normal C++ function inside a `cu` file and expose it in a standard C++ header file, which your `.cpp` file will include.

Comment: But how do I include a standard header file to linker these two compiler nvcc and C++?

Comment: I added #include "kernelAdd.h" into main.cpp, but it has error "Cannot open inlude file'kernelAdd.h'

Comment: **Comment 2:** In the same way as you usually do. Header files are consumed by compiler, not by linker. ``nvcc`` will most definitely be able to handle any standard header file. Just think of it as of a C++ compiler that supports some additional syntax. **Comment 5:** Sorry for asking that, but did you create the file in the same folder as your other source files? It works for me when I just compile everything from the command line, can't test with VS.

Comment: Many thanks again! I still haven't built it correctly. While I build it in only 1 file addFunc.cu, it builds correct, just have error when I separate it into 2 file: kernel .cu and main .cpp

Comment: If you have three files, ``addFunc.cu``, ``addFunc.h`` and ``mainFunc.cu`` with the contents from the answer, you should be able to build them from the command line as ``nvcc addFunc.cu mainFunc.cu``.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to create file addFunc.h, I just have 2 file kernel addFunc.cu and main file mainFunc.cpp

Comment: I tried to nvcc in command line, it's ok. But I want to build it into a project, it still doesn't work.

Comment: As you said, the host compiler does not understand the `<<<>>>` syntax so you need to put a stub (i.e. a wrapper) in the .cu file.