# CUDA Error C2059: syntax error: '<'

Tags: c++, cuda

I have troubles when compiling my code.

First of all, I have to state something:

1. I have no issues to run other simpler CUDA codes in my GTX650Ti GPU. [Thrust exception: "thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x00000000"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512284/thrust-exception-thrustsystemsystem-error-at-memory-location-0x00000000)
2. I've been working in a class with several methods and for some unknown reason, this program leads me to the error:
   Error C2059: syntax error: '<'

This is part of the code:

```
__global__ void linearSpaceKernel(double *result, double base, double delta, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < size)
        result[i] = base + double(i) * delta;
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
}

void foo::setRange(const double &lower, const double &upper, const unsigned int &samples)
{
    vector<double> result(samples);
    double dx = (upper - lower) / (samples - 1);
    if (isCUDA)
    {
        device_vector<double> dev_result(samples);
        linearSpaceKernel<<<1, samples>>>(raw_pointer_cast(dev_result.data()), lower, dx, samples);
        thrust::copy(dev_result.begin(), dev_result.end(), result.begin());
    }
    else
    {       
        double summation = lower;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
        {
            result[i] = summation;
            summation += dx;
        }       
    }
    dis = result;
}
```

I omitted the CUDA error functions and the rest of the code to keep my code short and clear.

I have to clear that ***setRange*** is a class member function of ***foo*** that calls the kernel ***linearSpaceVector()***. This class provides a Boolean called ***isCUDA*** which is used to let the user decide if the execution will be performed in the host or in the device.
At the end, both execution options update the vector ***dis***, which is a class member vector.

The main function is defined in ***fooTest.cu*** as follows:

```
#include "foo.cuh"

int main()
{
    CUDAinit();
    foo A;
    A.isCUDA = true;
    A.setRange(0, 1, 100);
    cin.get();
}
```

The output is the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: fs, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\..\..\..\OneDrive\Documentos\Cátedras CONACyT\UTM\Research\FLS\Programs\fsTest.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Arturo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\fs\fs>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o Debug\fsTest.cu.obj "C:\Users\Arturo\OneDrive\Documentos\Cátedras CONACyT\UTM\Research\FLS\Programs\fsTest.cu" 
1>  fsTest.cu
1>  fs.cu
1>  c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.5\include\thrust\system\detail\error_category.inl(102): warning C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h(168) : see declaration of 'strerror'
1>  c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.5\include\thrust\system\cuda\detail\bulk\detail\pointer_traits.hpp(55): warning C4800: 'unsigned int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>  c:\users\arturo\onedrive\documentos\cátedras conacyt\utm\research\fls\programs\fs.cu(332): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And the errors are listed as:

```
3   Error   C2059: syntax error : '<'   c:\users\arturo\onedrive\documentos\cátedras conacyt\utm\research\fls\programs\fs.cu    332 1   fs
4   IntelliSense: expected an expression    c:\Users\Arturo\OneDrive\Documentos\Cátedras CONACyT\UTM\Research\FLS\Programs\fs.cu    332 23  fs
Warning 2   warning C4800: 'unsigned int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)   c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.5\include\thrust\system\cuda\detail\bulk\detail\pointer_traits.hpp    55  1   fs
Warning 1   warning C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.    c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.5\include\thrust\system\detail\error_category.inl 102 1   fs
```

Comment: Your problem resembles the one discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200952/how-to-separate-the-kernel-file-cuda-with-the-main-cpp-file

Comment: I have to clear something else. I have renamed my codes to .cu and .cuh and the result is the same. As the code shows, the main function is defined in fooTest.cu.

Comment: The error message should indicate *where* the error is.

Comment: (also, I assume it is s**y**ntax error, not s**i**ntax error?)

Comment: Error is in the triple angle brackets. Also, I tried making a little project to test this function separating that part of my project code. It works perfectly. I don't understand why! What is my mistake?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using the cuda compiler to compile this file, then. I've not used cuda through MSVC, so I can't suggest what you might be doing wrong configuring your project.

Comment: Indeed. The triple angle brackets are not C++ but it looks like they end up getting fed to the C++ compiler after all. You will need to post full output from the tool chain you are using: complete details of what commands are run with what arguments. Hopefully someone will then see what goes wrong.

Comment: I would understand that, Hurkyl, but other smaller projects can be compiled with VS. I will try to check the CUDA conifguration in my project again.

Answer (score 1):

I already discovered why my code generated that error!

This was the problem: I defined a header file called ***foo.cuh***. I only defined the class foo in there, but all the methods were defined in a separeted file called ***foo.cu*** (a source file).

When I copied all the ***foo.cu*** file and pasted it in the header file after the class definition, this error disappeared!!!

I think CUDA does not support the use of source files to define the class methods in a separate file. I mean that the NVCC compiler does not treat the source files; instead of that the C++ compiler tries to compile them.

What do you think?